# python permutation time limit exceeded

Tags: python-3.x, list, permutation

I have a number `n` which has max value till `1_000_000`

I have to  create a list with `li=range(0,n)` and find the permutation of 2 items

I am using this code

```
from itertools import permutations 
perm = permutations(li,2)
for i in list(perm): 
    print(i)
```

this code is working for small values of `n`

but if its big number I am getting time limit exceeded error

How can I solve these time out exceeded error without using external libraries

Comment: what is ur end goal? the permutation is towards solving a problem i bliv, so what is the problem? stating it might help provide a better way with the permutation

Comment: Your program is trying to print ``n!/(n-2)!`` permutations. For your ``n = 1000_000``, this is 9.99999 × 10¹¹ ≈ 2⁴⁰. While that is not computationally _infeasible_, it's highly impractical.

Comment: Python by itself won't throw such an error, but likely some coding challenge sites. What *exactly* are the constraints you have for your program? What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

do not cast to list your `perm` variable, just use your `perm` in your for loop:

```
for i in perm: 
    print(i)
```

take, care: your program will take a long, long time since you have `999999000000` lines to print

the reason to not cast to list your variable `perm` it is to not keep in memory all the permutations (you will get probably out of memory or will take a long time)